# Replace part of URL with IP adress

Tags: linux, sed

What I want to do is something like below. I have a URL, say http://www.google.com/one/two/three

I need to extract the main domain name "www.google.com", to feed it to nslookup (As nslookup/dig does not seem to work with full URL) and then replace the URL with resolved IP address.e.g.

```
$ echo "http://www.google.com/one/two/three" | sed "s/<pattern>//g" 
$ www.google.com
```

The problem is that "http://" may not always be there. And then

```
$ echo "http://www.google.com/one/two/three" | sed "s/<pattern>//g" 
$ http://11.22.33.44/one/two/three
```

Can anyone provide any related link or related examples ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this sed command:

```
echo "http://www.google.com/one/two/three" | sed -r 's#(https?://)?([^/]+).*#\2#'
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
www.google.com
```

And when you have fetched IP address:

```
$> IP="11.22.33.44"
$> echo "https://www.google.com/one/two/three" | sed -r "s#(https?://)?([^/]+)(.*)#\1$IP\3#"
https://11.22.33.44/one/two/three
```

This will work with `http://`, `https://` or without any `https?://` before the URL.

Comment: You're most welcome, glad that it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

Since URL's can be messy ("http://user:pass@www.example.com:8080/one/two/three") in the general case I'd recommend using a language with a URI parsing library. For example

```
url="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087200/replace-part-of-url-with-ip-adress"
newurl=$(perl -MURI -le '
    $uri = URI->new(shift);
    $cmd = "nslookup " . $uri->host;
    $out = qx($cmd);
    if ($out =~ /Name:.*?\KAddress:\s+([\d.]+)/s) { 
        $ip = $1;
        $uri->host($ip);
        print $uri
    } else {warn "cannot find IP address in nslookup output"}
' "$url")
echo "$newurl"
```

outputs

```
http://198.252.206.16/questions/18087200/replace-part-of-url-with-ip-adress
```