# Zero padding numbers in a Bash loop

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to make a list with a simple bash looping

I want this:

```
000000
000001
000002
```

They give me this:

```
0
1
2
```

My shell code:

```
countBEG="000000"
countEND="999999"


while [ $countBEG != $countEND ]
do
        echo "$countBEG"
        countBEG=$[$countBEG +1]
done
```

Comment: The problem is that when you use arithmetic operations, leading zeroes are meaningless and thus stripped. You might want to work on numbers from the beginning, then pad them when you display them (with printf for example)

Comment: As an alternative `echo {000..009}` or `seq -f '%05g' 0 9`

Comment: *Numbers* aren't zero-padded; string representations of them are, and `$((...))` (don't use `$[...]`, it's long been deprecated) simply returns the simplest representation it can for its expression.

Comment: @Aaron, pedantically, leading zeroes are highly significant for arithmetic operations: they denote octal numbers: `x="08"; ((x++))`

Answer (score 3):

Change your `echo` to use printf, where you can specify format for left padding.

```
printf "%06d\n" "$countBEG"
```

This sets 6 as fixed length of the output, using zeros to fill empty spaces.

Comment: Thanks @123 for fixing the broken formatting. Was trying to figure out how to escape backticks :)

Comment: 4 space at the start of the line for a code-block, all other formatting is then ignored :)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for:

```
seq -w "$countBEG" "$countEND"
```

The `-w` option does the padding.

Comment: That's it. Thank you brow.

Comment: May I request you to [vote to undelete and reopen this question please](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18087200/548225)

Comment: @anubhava, done. How many undelete votes are required to re-open?

Comment: Thanks so much. It will need 1 more undelete vote. Please also vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

The following command will produce the desired output (no need for the loop) :

```
printf '%06d\n' {1..999999}
```

Explanation :

- `{1..999999}` is expanded by bash to the sequence of 1 to 999999
- the format string `'%06d\n'` tells `printf` to display the number it is given as argument padded to 6 digits and followed by a linefeed
- `printf` repeats this output if it is given more arguments than is defined in its format specification

Comment: why would you use `g` ?

Comment: Just a small change, OP needs 6 digits I think.

Comment: @123 because I don't know `printf` well and took the first that worked :-/ `d` is preferred I guess?

Comment: `g` will change larger number to scientific notation, not the zero padded string op wants

Comment: @123 thanks for the explanation, I've changed it to `d`

Comment: Starting in `bash` 4.0, brace expansion will preserve leading zeros, eliminating the need for `printf`: `{001..100}` produces `001 002 003 ... 100`.

Comment: Thanks @chepner. I won't be including this in my answer though as it has already be mentioned as a comment on the question and doesn't handle the linefeeds (I checked whether `{001\n..100\n}` was expanded to the desired output, but unsurprisingly it isn't a valid brace syntax)

Comment: Hmmm actually `echo {001..100}"<linefeed>"` (with a literal linefeed instead of `<linefeed>`) seems to kinda work... I've just got an extra leading whitespace from somewhere on all lines but the first

Comment: Mystery solved : the extra space is the one `echo` adds between every argument it is given. Brace expansion will produce the `001\n`, `002\n`, ..., `100\n` arguments, which will be displayed separated by spaces.